# Comparing Data between 2 different files in Unix

Tags: shell-script, files, comm

I have 2 different files-

File 1

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
```

File 2

```
2
3
5
6
10
12
```

I want to compare 2 files and get the output data which is in File 1 but not in File 2-

Output

```
4
8
```

I am using below command but not getting desired output-

> comm -23 file1 file2

Comment: I think the problem is `comm` expects a lexicographic sort which is different from the numeric order of your inputs. Lexicographically, `1`, `10`, and `12` all need to sort before `2`, so you need to resort your file1 and file2 to use comm.

Comment: You'd be getting an error from `comm`. It's _always_ important to share these in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `comm` to work properly, both files have to be sorted lexicographically, not numerically.  You may sort your files before calling `comm` using

```
sort -o file1 file1
sort -o file2 file2
```

Then:

```
$ comm -23 file1 file2
4
8
```

Or, you may sort the files at the same time as you call `comm`, if your shell supports process substitutions:

```
$ comm -23 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
4
8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep

```
grep -F -x -f 'File2' -v 'File1'
```

Pattern of fixed--strings (-F) in File2 (-f)

Use `-x` to match whole lines. Otherwise "0123" in File1 would be excluded from the output due to "12" in File2.

find similar line and inverse with (-v)